# How to check Ray Picking Cylinders XNA

Tags: c#, xna, drawing, primitive, bounding-box

I'm drawing cylinders using the primitives provided by XNA, and what I want to do is, when the mouse hovers on a cylinder, I detect it. I tried using bounding spheres but it didn't work, as it wasn't accurate. I don't know what to do. Any help?

**Summary of what I want to do. 
1- Create bounding Box for this Cylinder
2- Rotate this bounding Box.**

**CODE TO DRAW CYLINDER**  can be found here

http://xbox.create.msdn.com/en-US/education/catalog/sample/primitives_3d

```
#region File Description
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// CylinderPrimitive.cs
//
// Microsoft XNA Community Game Platform
// Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endregion

#region Using Statements
using System;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
#endregion

namespace TheProteinBundle
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Geometric primitive class for drawing cylinders.
    /// </summary>
    public class CylinderPrimitive : GeometricPrimitive
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new cylinder primitive, using default settings.
        /// </summary>
        public CylinderPrimitive(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
            : this(graphicsDevice, 1, 1, 32)
        {
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Constructs a new cylinder primitive,
        /// with the specified size and tessellation level.
        /// </summary>
        public CylinderPrimitive(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice,
                                 float height, float diameter, int tessellation)
        {
            if (tessellation < 3)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("tessellation");

            height /= 2;

            float radius = diameter / 2;

            // Create a ring of triangles around the outside of the cylinder.
            for (int i = 0; i < tessellation; i++)
            {
                Vector3 normal = GetCircleVector(i, tessellation);

                AddVertex(normal * radius + Vector3.Up * height, normal);
                AddVertex(normal * radius + Vector3.Down * height, normal);

                AddIndex(i * 2);
                AddIndex(i * 2 + 1);
                AddIndex((i * 2 + 2) % (tessellation * 2));

                AddIndex(i * 2 + 1);
                AddIndex((i * 2 + 3) % (tessellation * 2));
                AddIndex((i * 2 + 2) % (tessellation * 2));
            }

            // Create flat triangle fan caps to seal the top and bottom.
            CreateCap(tessellation, height, radius, Vector3.Up);
            CreateCap(tessellation, height, radius, Vector3.Down);

            InitializePrimitive(graphicsDevice);

            base.boundingSphere.Center = Vector3.Zero;
            if (height > diameter)
                base.boundingSphere.Radius = height;
            else
                base.boundingSphere.Radius = diameter;
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Helper method creates a triangle fan to close the ends of the cylinder.
        /// </summary>
        void CreateCap(int tessellation, float height, float radius, Vector3 normal)
        {
            // Create cap indices.
            for (int i = 0; i < tessellation - 2; i++)
            {
                if (normal.Y > 0)
                {
                    AddIndex(CurrentVertex);
                    AddIndex(CurrentVertex + (i + 1) % tessellation);
                    AddIndex(CurrentVertex + (i + 2) % tessellation);
                }
                else
                {
                    AddIndex(CurrentVertex);
                    AddIndex(CurrentVertex + (i + 2) % tessellation);
                    AddIndex(CurrentVertex + (i + 1) % tessellation);
                }
            }

            // Create cap vertices.
            for (int i = 0; i < tessellation; i++)
            {
                Vector3 position = GetCircleVector(i, tessellation) * radius +
                                   normal * height;

                AddVertex(position, normal);
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Helper method computes a point on a circle.
        /// </summary>
        static Vector3 GetCircleVector(int i, int tessellation)
        {
            float angle = i * MathHelper.TwoPi / tessellation;

            float dx = (float)Math.Cos(angle);
            float dz = (float)Math.Sin(angle);

            return new Vector3(dx, 0, dz);
        }
    }
}
```

Using this class

```
#region File Description
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// GeometricPrimitive.cs
//
// Microsoft XNA Community Game Platform
// Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#endregion

#region Using Statements
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework;
using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
#endregion

namespace TheProteinBundle
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Base class for simple geometric primitive models. This provides a vertex
    /// buffer, an index buffer, plus methods for drawing the model. Classes for
    /// specific types of primitive (CubePrimitive, SpherePrimitive, etc.) are
    /// derived from this common base, and use the AddVertex and AddIndex methods
    /// to specify their geometry.
    /// </summary>
    public abstract class GeometricPrimitive : IDisposable
    {
        #region Fields


        // During the process of constructing a primitive model, vertex
        // and index data is stored on the CPU in these managed lists.
        List<VertexPositionNormal> vertices = new List<VertexPositionNormal>();
        List<ushort> indices = new List<ushort>();


        // Once all the geometry has been specified, the InitializePrimitive
        // method copies the vertex and index data into these buffers, which
        // store it on the GPU ready for efficient rendering.
        VertexBuffer vertexBuffer;
        IndexBuffer indexBuffer;
        BasicEffect basicEffect;

        public BoundingSphere boundingsphere2;
        public BoundingSphere boundingSphere;
        public Matrix world;
        #endregion

        #region Initialization


        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a new vertex to the primitive model. This should only be called
        /// during the initialization process, before InitializePrimitive.
        /// </summary>
        protected void AddVertex(Vector3 position, Vector3 normal)
        {
            vertices.Add(new VertexPositionNormal(position, normal));
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Adds a new index to the primitive model. This should only be called
        /// during the initialization process, before InitializePrimitive.
        /// </summary>
        protected void AddIndex(int index)
        {
            if (index > ushort.MaxValue)
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("index");

            indices.Add((ushort)index);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Queries the index of the current vertex. This starts at
        /// zero, and increments every time AddVertex is called.
        /// </summary>
        protected int CurrentVertex
        {
            get { return vertices.Count; }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Once all the geometry has been specified by calling AddVertex and AddIndex,
        /// this method copies the vertex and index data into GPU format buffers, ready
        /// for efficient rendering.
        protected void InitializePrimitive(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice)
        {
            // Create a vertex declaration, describing the format of our vertex data.

            // Create a vertex buffer, and copy our vertex data into it.
            vertexBuffer = new VertexBuffer(graphicsDevice,
                                            typeof(VertexPositionNormal),
                                            vertices.Count, BufferUsage.None);

            vertexBuffer.SetData(vertices.ToArray());

            // Create an index buffer, and copy our index data into it.
            indexBuffer = new IndexBuffer(graphicsDevice, typeof(ushort),
                                          indices.Count, BufferUsage.None);

            indexBuffer.SetData(indices.ToArray());

            // Create a BasicEffect, which will be used to render the primitive.
            basicEffect = new BasicEffect(graphicsDevice);

            basicEffect.EnableDefaultLighting();            
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Finalizer.
        /// </summary>
        ~GeometricPrimitive()
        {
            Dispose(false);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Frees resources used by this object.
        /// </summary>
        public void Dispose()
        {
            Dispose(true);
            GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Frees resources used by this object.
        /// </summary>
        protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                if (vertexBuffer != null)
                    vertexBuffer.Dispose();

                if (indexBuffer != null)
                    indexBuffer.Dispose();

                if (basicEffect != null)
                    basicEffect.Dispose();
            }
        }


        #endregion


        public void TransformBoundingSphere(Matrix TransformToWorld)
        {
            boundingSphere.Transform(ref TransformToWorld, out boundingsphere2);
        }
        public bool CheckRayIntersection(Ray ray)
        {
            if (ray.Intersects(boundingsphere2).HasValue) return true;

            return false;
        }
        #region Draw


        /// <summary>
        /// Draws the primitive model, using the specified effect. Unlike the other
        /// Draw overload where you just specify the world/view/projection matrices
        /// and color, this method does not set any renderstates, so you must make
        /// sure all states are set to sensible values before you call it.
        /// </summary>
        public void Draw(Effect effect)
        {
            GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice = effect.GraphicsDevice;

            // Set our vertex declaration, vertex buffer, and index buffer.
            graphicsDevice.SetVertexBuffer(vertexBuffer);

            graphicsDevice.Indices = indexBuffer;            


            foreach (EffectPass effectPass in effect.CurrentTechnique.Passes)
            {
                effectPass.Apply();

                int primitiveCount = indices.Count / 3;

                graphicsDevice.DrawIndexedPrimitives(PrimitiveType.TriangleList, 0, 0,
                                                     vertices.Count, 0, primitiveCount);

            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Draws the primitive model, using a BasicEffect shader with default
        /// lighting. Unlike the other Draw overload where you specify a custom
        /// effect, this method sets important renderstates to sensible values
        /// for 3D model rendering, so you do not need to set these states before
        /// you call it.
        /// </summary>
        public void Draw(Matrix world, Matrix view, Matrix projection, Color color)
        {
            // Set BasicEffect parameters.
            basicEffect.World = world;
            basicEffect.View = view;
            basicEffect.Projection = projection;
            basicEffect.DiffuseColor = color.ToVector3();
            basicEffect.Alpha = color.A / 255.0f;

            GraphicsDevice device = basicEffect.GraphicsDevice;
            device.DepthStencilState = DepthStencilState.Default;

            if (color.A < 255)
            {
                // Set renderstates for alpha blended rendering.
                device.BlendState = BlendState.AlphaBlend;
            }
            else
            {
                // Set renderstates for opaque rendering.
                device.BlendState = BlendState.Opaque;
            }

            // Draw the model, using BasicEffect.
            Draw(basicEffect);
        }


        #endregion
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you post any relevant code you may have? You could look at using a `ray` object. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13042318/ray-intersection-with-3d-quads-in-xna and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.ray.intersects.aspx

Comment: I've added where I draw cylinders from I just can't figure out how to create bounding boxes for these cylinders